"Failed to Fetch Font Resource from Google Fonts"
The request to fetch the font file from the specified URL failed multiple times.
Specific URL: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v13/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa0ZL7W0Q5n-wU.woff2 and https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v13/UcC73FwrK3iLTeHuS_fvQtMwCp50KnMa2JL7W0Q5n-wU.woff2.
Error occurred during multiple retry attempts
Actions Taken:

Checked Network Connection: Verified that the internet connection is
stable and other websites are accessible.
Cleared Cache and Cookies: Cleared the browser cache and cookies to
rule out any issues caused by stale data.
Disabled Extensions: Disabled any browser extensions,
such as ad blockers, that might interfere with the request.
Attempted Multiple Browsers: Tried accessing the page on different browsers
(e.g., Chrome, Firefox) to ensure it's not a browser-specific issue.
Verified URL: Double-checked the URL to ensure there were no typos
or errors.
Checked Google Fonts Status: Looked at the Google Fonts
status page to see if there were any reported outages or issues.
Tried Different Network: Tested the request on a different network
to rule out local network issues.
Review Console Errors: Examined the
browser console for any additional error messages or hints
that might explain the failure.

Expected Outcome:
The font file should be successfully downloaded from the provided URL.
The font should be applied to the text on the webpage, ensuring the correct appearance as defined in the CSS.
No errors or retries should occur during the request, indicating a smooth and successful fetch of the font file.
Actual Outcome:
The request to fetch the font file failed, even after multiple retry attempts.
The font was not applied to the text, resulting in the fallback font being used instead.
The browser console displayed errors indicating the failure of the request, without providing a clear reason for the failure.

Both URLs seem to work fine. Please add more details e.g about your @font-face rules or the JS for fetching files – what are the error messages?. This may not work if you're trying to fetch files via JS in file mode - so if you're not running in a local server environment. Keep in mind a font-face alone won't apply any fonts unless you add CSS rules for certain HTML elements.

Which error/status code do you get (on your device/in your network), if you open https://www.gstatic.com? Also: Please share a minimal reproducible example!

I have a complex header Content-Security-Policy in .htaccess file. Below are some of the directives I had. I added these values ​​to make it work. Don't forget that the service worker will use an older Content-Security-Policy. Make sure it uses the new header.
connect-src fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com; 
style-src fonts.googleapis.com; 
style-src-elem fonts.googleapis.com; 
font-src fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com

